# beamer: suppress frames in handout mode gives spurios inclusion

Tags: beamer, xetex, overlays

While making lecture slides with *XeTeX* & *beamer* I stumbled across a problem with the exclusion of certain slides in handout mode.

Since this appears to be spurious I have difficulties in providing a minimal code example right now.

I have one slide contents in a separate file, which contains a list of `\onslide<i>{}` points. I include this file several times in order to go through the list step by step intermixing it with other slides on the *beamer*. On the *handout* on the other hand I only want to show the full list once.

```
\begin{frame}<beamer:1-3>{title}  % should appear both on the beamer and in the handout
  \input{external_file}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{other title}        % beamer & handout
  \input{other_external_file}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<beamer:4-6| handout:0>{title}   % on beamer only
  \input{external_file}
\end{frame}
```

What happens if I do it like this, is that contents from the suppressed frame suddenly appears two slides later down the road on the handouts.

I have been using *beamer* for several years and many lectures by now - am I missing something here? Some (stupid) mistake from my side?

Comment: What happens if you don't use underscores in your files?

Comment: user36478 did you try with files lacking underscores in their names? Any change in behavior?